# Why doesn't using boost::tuple's .get work in template functions in gcc?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, g++, tuples

While trying to port some code to compile in linux I get peculiar compilation errors. Searching  through the codebase I finally manage to get it down to the following code.

```
 5: // include and using statements
 6: template<typename RT, typename T1>
 7: RT func(tuple<T1> const& t) {
 8:     return t.get<0>();
 9: }
10: // test code
```

Trying to use it I get the error:

```
test.cpp: In function <functionName>:
test.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

The code works fine in Visual Studio but for some reason I can't figure out why it doesn't work with g++. Anyone here got a clue how on how to work around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need some `template` love:

```
return t.template get<0>();
```

Visual C++ does not parse templates correctly, which is why it incorrectly accepts the code without the `template` keyword.  For more information on why the `template` is required here, see the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ ["Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)